# Puma started with Overmind sometimes not bound to localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dns, puma

When I am running my Rails 7 app locally, I usually start it with `overmind start`. This launches my Puma server `Puma version: 5.6.5 (ruby 3.1.2-p20) ("Birdie's Version")` and reports `Listening on http://127.0.0.1:5000`

Usually, I can access this via `localhost` using `localhost:5000`. Sometimes when this starts, though, it's not reachable. I can access it via `127.0.0.1:5000`. This behavior sometimes fixes itself after a few minutes.

I'm guessing some sort of local dns caching behavior? Not sure where to look.

EDIT: Add Procfile

```bash
# Procfile
web: bin/rails server -p $PORT
css: yarn build:css --watch
js: yarn build --reload
```

Comment: what does your hosts file look like?

Comment: I have a Procfile, but no hosts file

Comment: your os hosts file -- which you will have